# Get rid of repetitive code (Procedure Too Large Error)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get rid of these large blocks of repetitive code using "For Each" or any other helpful approach

I only have the blocks of code repeated about 70 times but since it contains multiple dynamic values, I find it hard to use a "For Each"

```
Public Sub ToTextBox()
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Set wsA = Sheets("Compute")

'1
With Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 1")
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = wsA.Range("b" & Range("L2")).Value & Chr(10) & wsA.Range("c" & Range("L2")).Value
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Size = 7
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
End With

    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 1A").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("a" & Range("L2")).Value
    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 1B").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("k" & Range("L2")).Value
    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 1C").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("j" & Range("L2")).Value

'2   
With Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 2")
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = wsA.Range("b" & Range("L2") + 1).Value & Chr(10) & wsA.Range("c" & Range("L2") + 1).Value
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Size = 7
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
End With

    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 2A").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("a" & Range("L2") + 1).Value
    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 2B").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("k" & Range("L2") + 1).Value
    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 2C").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("j" & Range("L2") + 1).Value

'3    
With Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 3")
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = wsA.Range("b" & Range("L2") + 2).Value & Chr(10) & wsA.Range("c" & Range("L2") + 2).Value
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Size = 7
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
End With

    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 3A").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("a" & Range("L2") + 2).Value
    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 3B").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("k" & Range("L2") + 2).Value
    Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 3C").TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet3.Range("j" & Range("L2") + 2).Value

'and 72 others


End Sub
```

Looking for a loop approach to compress this code

Answer (score -1):

Turn this:

```
With Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox 1")
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = wsA.Range("b" & Range("L2")).Value & Chr(10) & wsA.Range("c" & Range("L2")).Value
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Size = 7
    .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Name = "Verdana"
    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
End With
```

Into this:

```
Sub ShapeStuff(number as Long, sourceSheet as Worksheet)
    With Sheets("Slide Data").Shapes("TextBox " & cstr(number))
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = sourceSheet.Range("b" & sourceSheet.Range("L2") + number - 1).Value & Chr(10) & sourceSheet.Range("c" & Range("L2") + number - 1).Value
        .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Bold = True
        .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Size = 7
        .TextFrame.Characters(1, 7).Font.Name = "Verdana"
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
    End With
End Sub
```

Then call `ShapeStuff(1, wsA)`, `ShapeStuff(2, wsA)` and `ShapeStuff(3, wsA)` instead